# Is there any harm from having 'too many' thread groups in jmeter?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I've got to a point where one of the architectural solutions for one of my .jmx files is to increase Thread group number to ~60 Thread groups.

I've tried this as an experiment, and it works ok. My request are rather simple - just hitting different endpoints and checking some stuff...

Resources release fast.
I see no multithreading issues. CPU & Memory usage seems fine.

But I feel it's wrong to have 'too many' thread groups. Are there any tangible reasons for my concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having some much Thread Groups is strange but it can have an explanation.

Why do you need 60 ?

Regarding impact, it has a memory impact, the more you use Test elements the more you consume memory but it can be acceptable.

Comment: Why? - I'm testing Api methods, so they are rather independent & scenario-free (for now). The solution was to group methods acc to the controllers they belong to. So, to have an atomic configuration for each group of methods I've separated them with thread groups.

Comment: looks of to me in this case.